# What is the default password for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: password, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative (root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password)

I've just had someone install Ubuntu 12.04. I am not a techie - just a user. I am now asked for a password which I do not have and has never been set. Is there a default one? Otherwise I have to work as a guest all the time... Not so great. I appreciate any help.

Comment: One cannot install Ubuntu without setting up one user and his/her password. Ask the person who installed Ubuntu.

Comment: In this situation, the solution is to **reset the password**, which you can do with [any of the techniques described here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password).

Comment: @EliahKagan Am I missing something here? Rob H never set an Ubuntu user password. He doesn't want to reset his user password. He just wants to know how to get to his own user's desktop environment. If this comment makes sense please vote to reopen this useful canonical question which has been viewed 205k times.

Answer (score 6):

During installation you're asked to set a password. If you didn't set it yourself, ask the guy who installed it or to get it reset for you. There's no backdoor or default password with privileges to reset it.

However more advanced tricks are available to reset it of course. Here's a guide for example: ["How to reset your password in Ubuntu"](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword). It does require some 'techie' skills.

Answer (score 1):

Generally ubuntu will be the both username and password . if its not then ubuntu will be  username and then give a enter as assuming  blank password .

Comment: This is true for the LiveCD **not** for an Installed System, unless specified.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default password for Ubuntu or any sane operating system.

During the installation a username and password is specified.

Having a default username/password would be a bad idea from a security perspective.

Imagine if all Visa cards had a "default" PIN. And you didn't have to change it at first use. The first thing anyone would try would be the well known default PIN.